# MonkeyTalk not able to recognize drop down options

Tags: android, monkeytalk

While recording Monkey talk recorded it as

app.view("#4").tap

the same command is not working when I play back.
Monkey talk component id for the same is "paramItemOptionCheckbox"

I tried with
app.view("paramItemOptionCheckbox").tap but I am getting failure message as

FAILURE: Unable to find View('paramItemOptionCheckbox')

Then I tried with
app.view("#4").tap("paramItemOptionCheckbox");

and I got this message : Completed Script Playback - OK
but in application there is no action performed.

Can you please provide your help to find some workaround.

Thanks in advance,
Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command:

```
app.checkBox("paramItemOptionCheckbox").tap();
```